# Visual Studio 2010 + Intel i5 2500k

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Not sure if this is the right place for this, but since I know you all use VS2010...

I'm just about to pull the trigger on purchasing a bunch of new components for a new build based around an Intel i5 2500k processor. However, I came across a couple of posts that indicated that Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, when installed to a build with an i5 2500k processor would give a "processor not supported" error message and abort installation.

Considering that the bulk of my work on this machine will be done in Visual Studio 2010, this is a little concerning. Does anyone have any information on this? Or is anyone running an i5 2500k with VS2010 and no problems?

[Link #1](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/305229-28-intel-2500k-processor-supported-visual-studio-2010)

[Link #2](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/241351-49-microsoft-visual-studio-2010-hyperthread) - See the last comment in the thread.

Comment: Hmm. Normally I'd be inclined to say this is off-topic, but if this is possibly true, it's definitely something that is worth discussing on a developer Q&A (even if it is eventually closed as "too localized"). There might be some self-serving tendencies in my opinion too, though, since I'm also considering a similar purchase...

Comment: Do you have links to the original posts you saw? Were they on MSDN forums or Reddit? That kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got VS 2010 installed on my machine and I run an Intel i5 2500k. No problems for me so far.

Comment: Thanks, this is good news! I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if I can get some more feedback.

Comment: It's quite puzzling what these people are talking about, then. Could it be something to do with overclocking? Do you have your 2500k overclocked? Also, if you don't mind, I have another question: Have you tried or do you know if it's possible to use the onboard graphics *and* a graphics card simultaneously?

Comment: I don't currently have it overclocked, but I'm almost certain that when I installed Visual Studio the chip was overclocked. I haven't even looked at the onboard graphics. I'm not even sure my board supports it (I have an Asus P8P67, and I think its only the H67 boards that have a vga/dvi port).

Comment: The P8P67 (same board I have) does not have on board graphics. I ended up buying all the parts for this build, I DO have it overclocked to 4.2ghz (not too aggressive) and VS2010 installed just fine.

Comment: I get weird behavior when I go over 4.3, as long as I keep the turbo under that though there are no problems.  I have been using the vs2010 2500k combination for a year now and will probably continue to for several more.